# Custom Timeseries index in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, time-series, aws-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-indices

Is it possible to create custom timestamp index in elastic search?

While reading through elastic search, I find that elastic search automatically creates data insert timestamp if we enable @timestamp in mapping section. [elastic blog reference](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-as-a-time-series-data-store)

Now lets say I'm trying to create custom timeseries index on another index say promiseDate, so while querying on timeslice like last 10 mins or last 1 hour - does elasic search tries to scan each promiseDate present in the store for all the documents or its trying pull only those indexes lying on that specific timeseries?

Additionally,

1. Can this promiseDate be set as TimeSeriesFilter in Kibana?

Comment: what version of elasticsearch are you using. the blog post you're mentioning is 5 years old. If I'm not mistaken, newer versions do not add a timestamp automatically

Comment: alkis-kalogeris@ I'm working with es version 6 and above. So, is it possible to create time series index? And if yes, what's the mechanism? And also the questions I asked in the description.